# js setInterval - increase speed gradually

Tags: javascript, setinterval

How can I make setInterval to increase speed gradually, like start from 1000 ms and than go down until 40 ms gradually in few seconds by 1 ms at a time.

Any thoughts?

This is my code:

```
setTimeout(function() {bonustimer = setInterval(function() { handleTimer2(rushcount); }, 40);}, 1000);


handleTimer2 = function() {
if(rushcount === -1) {
clearInterval(bonustimer);      
} else {
$('.digit-wrapper').html(rushcount);
rushcount--;
}}
```

Comment: It's not practical to use `setInterval()` for this; use `setTimeout()` to get better control.

Comment: Also, explain "in few seconds by 1ms at a time", because that would mean it takes 1000 + 999 + 998 + ... + 40ms to reach 40ms :)

Comment: I have a timer, and at the end of the level it counts down the time bonus remaining, I have it setuped at 40 ms, and I want to start counting down the remaining seconds more slow at the begning and than to increase more fast until 0. But I don't know how to make the interval ms dynamic.

Comment: Then you should probably take fixed percentages off the current time, e.g. 20% reduction at each step should take care of that.

Comment: How would that code look like?

Comment: It would probably look beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set interval probably wouldn't be what you want here, as you just end up killing it and redoing it on every iteration.  Much easier to use setTimeout, possibly something like this:

```
(function () {
    var interval = 1001;
    timer = function() {
        --interval;
        //do your thing here

        if (interval >= 40) {
            setTimeout(timer, interval);
        }
    };
    timer();
})();
```

Also note that if you only decrease the interval by one ms at a time, from 1000 down to 40, it takes quite a while to go through all those iterations.  You can always replace `--interval` by some other formula, like `interval = interval*0.9;` (to reduce by 10% each iteration) or whatever formula you want.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the code by @OldGeeksGuide just stops when the ***interval*** reaches 40. Needs a little improvement ;)

```
(function () {
    var interval = 1000;
    timer = function() {
        interval--;
        //do your thing here

        interval = interval < 40 ? 40 : interval;
        setTimeout(timer, interval);
    };
    timer();
})();
```

Then you could maybe need to stop this loop by wrapping the *setTimeout* with some *if* condition ;)